C# += operator overloading issues
I'm trying to overload operator += .. of course this's not possible by code but If I have not been fooled by docs once overloaded the + operator the += operator will be implicity overloaded.
public class Register {
    private byte data;

    public Register(byte value = 0x00) { data = value; }

    public Register(Register value)
    {
        data = value.data;
    }
    
    public static byte operator +(Register lvalue, byte rvalue)
    {
        return (byte)(lvalue.data + rvalue);
    }
    
    public static byte operator +(byte lvalue, Register rvalue)
    {
        return (byte)(lvalue + rvalue.data);
    }

    public static implicit operator byte(Register value) => value.data;
}

I tried with many other operator and the result is more or less the same.. the compiler complains (instead compile) about missing explicit cast.
The error is:

Compilation error (line 140, col 3): Cannot implicitly convert type
'byte' to 'Register'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
cast?)

Class fiddle

A = (Register)(A + (byte)0x0F); works

"the compiler complains" Please include the compiler error in the question too.

@phuzi I provided the fiddle just in case...

Sounds like you need an implicit conversion from byte to Register

But the error is not shown in the question.

Post the failing code and the actual compiler error in the question itself. The question's operators return a byte but register +=  is trying to assign the result to a Register variable

Your + operator returns a byte, so += is equivalent to:
Register = Register + byte

But the byte cannot be implicitly casted back to a Register (only explicitly). Either make your explicit operator Register(byte value) implicit:
public static implicit operator Register(byte value) => new Register(value);

or make your + operator return Register:
public static Register operator +(Register lvalue, byte rvalue)
{
    return (Register)(byte)(lvalue.data + rvalue);
}


"make your explicit operator Register(byte value) implicit" - or OP could "add another explicit operator that returns a Register rather than a byte"

@stuartd true, but you can't have the same operator with different return types (byte +(Register, byte) and Register +(Register,byte) doesn't compile); and they have an implicit cast from Register to byte if they needed the internal byte value anyways.

you should also decide if you really want Register to be immutable in that case, or not, because the way you do it, every operation will create a new Register on the heap, and  "Register" sounds a bit performance critical to me. if you dont want it immutable, you might think about not using operator overloading here, and stick to add, etc. methods

@MichaelSchönbauer don't be fooled by the name the Register class will not be used in performance related scenarios (it is part of an emulator but not a real-time one). But your point is interesting anyway....

@ipodtouch0218  added an implicit operator and now everything works.. thnx alot.
